# How can you edit the HTTPResponse before parsing in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert an HTTPResponse to an XML file and it has invalid characters so I want to convert the characters to valid characters before the conversion.

How do you do that?

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(detailed_report_url) as url:
    xml = et.parse(url)
xml_root = xml.getroot()
```

I converted to STRING and replaced the characters but I was not able to return the content to XML and I also want to save the conversion.

```
r = requests.get(detailed_report_url)
xml_to_str = str(r.content)
xml_to_str = re.sub(r'&#([a-zA-Z0-9]+);?', r'[#\1;]', xml_to_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get(detailed_report_url)
xml_to_str = str(r.content)
```

`r.content` is bytes instances, using `str` at it is not correct way to convert it into string, consider that

```
content = b"Hello World"
print(str(content)) # b'Hello World'
```

observe b-prefix and quotes, generally you should use `.decode` e.g. if you working with ASCII

```
content = b"Hello World"
print(content.decode("ascii")) # Hello World
```

requests' response has `.text` property which does provide response body as string.